# Restarting debugger in python container, vs code error

Tags: python, docker, visual-studio-code, docker-compose

when I connect my vs code debugger to my python container, everything works, but when I press restart on the debugger panel, fastapi restarts (I can see in the docker logs) but the debugger no longer works
this is the command in compose:

```
pip install debugpy -t /tmp && python -Xfrozen_modules=off /tmp/debugpy --wait-for-client --listen 0.0.0.0:5678 -m uvicorn main:app --host 0.0.0.0 --port 8000 --reload
```

and launch.json:

```
{
"version": "0.2.0",
"configurations": [
    {
        "name": "Python: Remote Attach",
        "type": "python",
        "request": "attach",
        "port": 5678,
        "host": "localhost",
        "pathMappings": [
            {
                "localRoot": "${workspaceFolder}",
                "remoteRoot": "/app"
            }
        ]
    }     
]}
```

the debugger panel on the left shows that the server process restarted but I can't continue, yet when I make a file change, stat reloads,'Shutting down' logs appears, and then I can again interact with the debugger panel.
Is this a bug? Do I have to add a config as to what happens when I click the restart button?

Comment: OK turns out I was putting my breakpoints in main.py, and the first run from compose, with the flag -Xfrozen_modules=off, let me debug main.py, but on restart, the flag seems to not be applied, therefore I cant breakpoint there. any idea to guarantee this flag always?